# allow_url_fopen add it into .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to add allow_url_fopen to my server using .htaccess because I don't have access it to add it directly.So I want to add it using .htaccess 
I search on google and found some solution that by adding this line to `.htaccss` it will work so I add it this `php_value allow_url_fopen On` into my existing .htaccess now complete code it this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|system|css|functions)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

but now I run my website it gives me **`Internal Server Error`**
can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: try to begin with `php_value allow_url_fopen On` in .htaccess, you can test it now

Comment: No It gives me same error. I added this line on top of the code in .htaccess

Comment: then, it means that your server might not support this type of configuration, what if you remove all rules and just `php_value allow_url_fopen On` ? and vice-versa?

Comment: My website is running live so there is no solution for this?

Comment: Ask your server admin to open it Manuel if that server support this

Comment: This can only work if a) PHP is running as an Apache module, and b) you have `AllowOverride Options` or `AllowOverride All` privileges granted – so go check/ask your server admin for that. http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using , if your version of PHP is  <= 4.3.4 then you cannot do it in you can only set it using [ini_set](https://www.php.net/ini_set) , [check this out](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) for more information

Answer (score 0):

you should place the custom `php.ini` file in every folder where you need the custom PHP settings to apply

add this code to this file:

code:

```
allow_url_fopen=on
```

Comment: I am working in Codeigniter framework,and I dont think it will run php.ini